# I am using MigraDoc and PdfSharp (.Net Standard), but when I'm trying to create a paragraph,I get an error: "No appropriate font found"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, pdfsharp, migradoc

I am using MigraDoc and PdfSharp (.Net Standard), but when I'm trying to create a `paragraph(section.AddParagraph("Text"))`, I get this error :

> "No appropriate font found"

For example, when I'm adding a paragraph:

```
section.AddParagraph("Text");
```

I get this error:

> "No appropriate font found"

Probably that's linked with using PdfSharp/MigraDoc .NET Standard port. If you have any solution, I'll be very thankful to know it.

PS: Sorry for my English!

Comment: You are not using the "official" versions of MigraDoc and PDFsharp under Windows, you are using an unnamed port on an unnamed operating system. It might help to name port and version to get platform-specific answers and platform-specific sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Check your implementation of `IFontResolver` and make sure to use only fonts supported by your font resolver.

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29059207/162529
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36177630/162529

Answer (score -1):

Base on my test, I reproduce the error message, the error is caused by the **Font**.

[image]

Maybe you use Font in your code.

```
    Paragraph para = sec.AddParagraph("Text");//sec.AddParagraph();
        para.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Justify;
        para.Format.Font.Name = "Tinos";
        para.Format.Font.Size = 12;
```

I add reference with the two .net standard package.

PDFSharp for .NET Standard 2.0 https://github.com/Didstopia/PDFSharp

MigraDoc for .NET Standard https://github.com/Connatix/MigraDoc

I use **Font Tinos** for example.

Create a **FontResolver** class first.

```
public class FontResolver : IFontResolver
{
    public string DefaultFontName => "Tinos";

    public byte[] GetFont(string faceName)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var assembly = typeof(FontResolver).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var resources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
            var resourceName = resources.First(x => x == faceName);
            using (var rs = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                rs.CopyTo(ms);
                ms.Position = 0;
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    public FontResolverInfo ResolveTypeface(string familyName, bool isBold, bool isItalic)
    {
        if (familyName.Equals("Tinos", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (isBold && isItalic)
            {
                return new FontResolverInfo("Tinos-BoldItalic.ttf");
            }
            else if (isBold)
            {
                return new FontResolverInfo("Tinos-Bold.ttf");
            }
            else if (isItalic)
            {
                return new FontResolverInfo("Tinos-Italic.ttf");
            }
            else
            {
                return new FontResolverInfo("Tinos-Regular.ttf");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

You could get the Tinos Fonts file from the link below.
https://github.com/Didstopia/PDFSharp/tree/master/Didstopia.PDFSharp.Tests/Fonts

**Updataed:**

Add the Fonts folder with files like below.

[image]

And add the code below to call `FontResolver` before you use the Font in your code.

```
   if (GlobalFontSettings.FontResolver == null)
        {
            GlobalFontSettings.FontResolver = new FontResolver();
        }
```

Comment: Should I put fonts in the same path as Fontresolver.cs?

Comment: Gives me error "Sequence contains no matching element".Where exactly should be placed fonts?

Comment: I update with my reply with the Fonts folder and the code you need to call before you use font. Please check the updated.